# How to execute a shell command with the current buffer content and open a new split buffer with the command output?

Tags: buffers, external-command

I have an external command which accepts a SQL. I want to execute it within vim while editing SQL. I found two ways but both are not very satisfying.

1. `:w !<cmd>`
   This passes the content of the current buffer to `<cmd>` and outputs the result. However, because the result is shown in vim command line area, if the result is long I cannot scroll up/down the result.
2. `:%! <cmd>`
   This replaces the current buffer content with the cmd output, this is not what I want because I want to preserve the SQL.

If I can see the output in a new horizontal split buffer, it would be very nice. Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `:terminal <command> %` (make sure to save the buffer first).

Comment: Thanks Ben! The terminal window is really satisfying. I wanted to pass the buffer content, not a filename. But this can be achieved by `:terminal sh -c "cat % | <cmd>"`.

Comment: @jyshin programmatically you could also use `term_start()` with `in_io` set to `"buffer"` and `in_buf` the buffer number.

Answer (score 1):

```
:new +put=system('foobar',0)
```

Or

<kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>=</kbd>`system("foobar", 0)`<kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>

See `:h :put`, `:h system()`, `:h quote=`.